# How to download shiny graph in PDF Formart

Tags: r, data-visualization, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to R programming. I have developed a shiny dashboard application for different visualization purposes where I am plotting various graphs with the help of `renderDataTable`, `renderPlot`, `renderRpivotTable`, `renderImage renderInfoBox`.

But I am unable to figure out what is the best way to download these `graphs/charts/table/infobox` in PDF format.

So for I am rendering Rmarkdown within downloadHandler to achieve this requirement. But It is not working for every plot such `renderInfoBox`,`renderDataTable`. I will highly appreciate any inputs on this.